# $p^2 \mid mn \rightarrow p^2 \mid m \text{ or } p^2 \mid n$ ??

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm stuck on the following proof:

> $p^2 \mid m \text{  or  } p^2 \mid n \leftrightarrow p^2 \mid mn$

Now the forward implication is pretty obvious, but I'm not sure what to do in order to prove it in the other direction. All I keep writing is that:

> $c \cdot p^2 = mn \text{ where } c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Not sure where to go after this

EDIT:

I see from the comments/answers that the proof isn't valid, so I've decided to copy the proof I'm trying to understand straight from my textbook to see if I'm translating something incorrectly.

The proof to this step is actually a sub-step to proving that the Möbius $\mu$ function is multiplicative, but here is what the text says:

> Now $m$ or $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime number if and only if $mn$ is divisible by the square of a prime number

So am I reading something incorrectly? Sorry for the stupid mistake if I am.

Comment: Are m and n relatively prime?

Comment: The statement is false. Take $p=3$, $m=n=3$.

Comment: I've adjusted the question

Comment: In the statement of the theorem (at least [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)) the integers are assumed to be coprime: an important hypothesis.

Comment: The co-prime is required as another example would be p=2,m=6,n=10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the hypothesis for the Möbius function, we know that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers. Then assume $p^2\mid mn$. This implies $p\mid mn$, hence $p\mid m$ or $p\mid n$. As $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $p$ cannot divide both. Without loss of generality, suppose $p\nmid n$ so that $p\mid m$. Then since $p^2\mid mn$ and $p$ does not divide $n$, we have $p^2\mid m$.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you took a look at the edit

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the integers should be coprime (relatively prime).

Comment: How would the proof work if they were coprime? Does it work in that case?

Comment: Exactly like I've written above; coprime and relatively prime mean the same thing. It's equivalent to $\gcd(m,n)=1$, which is why $p$ cannot divide both $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Just one last question, why does $p^2 \mid mn \rightarrow p \mid mn$?

Comment: $p\mid p^2$ and $p^2\mid mn$, thus $p\mid mn$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion is certainly not true. Take $p=2$ and $m=n=2$ for example.

Comment: More generally let $p$ be any prime, and set $m=n=p$.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you took a look at the edit